# Merge certain rows in a DataFrame based on startswith

Tags: pandas, startswith

I have a DataFrame, in which I want to merge certain rows to a single one. It has the following structure (values repeat)

```
Index   Value
1      date:xxxx
2      user:xxxx
3      time:xxxx
4      description:xxx1
5      xxx2
6      xxx3
7      billed:xxxx
...
```

Now the problem is, that the columns 5 & 6 still belong to the description and were separated just wrong (whole string separated by ","). I want to merge the "description" row (4) with the values afterwards (5,6). In my DF, there can be 1-5 additional entries which have to be merged with the description row, but the structure allows me to work with `startswith`, because no matter how many rows have to be merged, the end point is always the row which starts with "billed". Due to me being very new to python, I haven´t got any code written for this problem yet.

My thought is the following (if it is even possible):

> Look for a row which starts with "description" → Merge all the rows afterwards till reaching the row which starts with "billed", then stop (obviosly we keep the "billed" row) → Do the same to each row starting with "description"

New DF should look like:

```
Index   Value
1      date:xxxx
2      user:xxxx
3      time:xxxx
4      description:xxx1, xxx2, xxx3
5      billed:xxxx
...
```

Comment: [jfyi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). could you show expected `df`?

Comment: Added to the main post

Comment: I think is not possible using `pandas`. Only through loops/iterations.

Comment: Could you help me by giving me a structure of such a loop/iteration?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Value': ('date:xxxx', 'user:xxxx', 'time:xxxx', 'description:xxx', 'xxx2', 'xxx3', 'billed:xxxx')})
records = []
description = description_val = None

for rec in df.to_dict('records'):  # type: dict
    # if previous description and record startswith previous description value
    if description and rec['Value'].startswith(description_val):
        description['Value'] += ', ' + rec['Value']  # add record Value into previous description
        continue
    # record with new description...
    if rec['Value'].startswith('description:'):
        description = rec
        _, description_val = rec['Value'].split(':')
    elif rec['Value'].startswith('billed:'):
        # billed record - remove description value
        description = description_val = None

    records.append(rec)

print(pd.DataFrame(records))

#                          Value
# 0                    date:xxxx
# 1                    user:xxxx
# 2                    time:xxxx
# 3  description:xxx, xxx2, xxx3
# 4                  billed:xxxx
```